# What is the sequence of states that mysql goes through when altering a table

Tags: mysql, database-administration

When altering a table in MYSQL and viewing the operation in the administrator console, I see a field called state.   At the console, I am viewing, the state I see is "copy to tmp table" but I have no idea what stage in the process this indicates I am at.   Does anyone know the sequence of sub operations that MYSQL goes through when altering a table.   This would help make the information being displayed on the console more understandable.

Comment: denial, anger, depression, bargaining and acceptance

Comment: Funny but not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this documentation about MYSQL thread states that answers the question nicely.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html